# Loadash filter need to get exact match

Tags: lodash

When trying to filter array using Lodash, i am getting all the element of that array. Need to get the specific array only. Please find my coding so far

```
var sizeList = [{
                    id: 1,
                    title: "Test1",
                    type: [{
                        name: "1.1",
                        present: false
                    }, {
                        name: "1.2",
                        present: true
                    }, {
                        name: "1.3",
                        present: false
                    }]
                }, {
                    id: 2,
                    title: "Test2",
                    type: [{
                        name: "2.1",
                        present: false
                    }, {
                        name: "2.2",
                        present: true
                    }, {
                        name: "2.3",
                        present: false
                    }]
                }, {
                    id: 3,
                    title: "Test3",
                    type: [{
                        name: "3.1",
                        present: false
                    }, {
                        name: "3.2",
                        present: true
                    }, {
                        name: "3.3",
                        present: true
                    }]
                }],
                result = _.filter(sizeList, {
                    type: [{
                        name: '3.3'
                    }]
                });

            console.log(result);
```

My problem is, when i filter with name:3.3 i am getting all the element in Test3 array including 3.1, 3.2 and 3.3. I need to only 3.3. Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map the items after filtering by type, and filter the type array as well:

```js
var sizeList = [{"id":1,"title":"Test1","type":[{"name":"1.1","present":false},{"name":"1.2","present":true},{"name":"1.3","present":false}]},{"id":2,"title":"Test2","type":[{"name":"2.1","present":false},{"name":"2.2","present":true},{"name":"2.3","present":false}]},{"id":3,"title":"Test3","type":[{"name":"3.1","present":false},{"name":"3.2","present":true},{"name":"3.3","present":true}]}];

var result = _(sizeList)
  .filter({
    type: [{ name: '3.3' }]
  })
  .map(({ type, ...o }) => ({
    ...o,
    type: _.filter(type, { name: '3.3' })
  }))
  .value();

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank u very much for ur answer @Ori Drori.. :-)